# Problems setting up Extensible calendar

Tags: extjs, calendar, extjs4.1, extensible

I'm trying to set up an [Extensible Calendar Pro](http://ext.ensible.com/products/calendar/) in my ExtJs 4.1 application, but I still get a *name is undefined* error.

**EDIT:**

I solved the original problem, but directly went in another.

Updated code:

```
Ext.define('ZeuS.view.panels.ZeusMainPanel',{
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    id : 'zeusMainPanel',
    alias : 'widget.zeus',

requires : [
    'Extensible.Extensible',
    'Extensible.calendar.CalendarPanel',
    'Extensible.calendar.data.MemoryEventStore',
    'Extensible.calendar.data.EventModel',
    'Extensible.calendar.view.*'
],

    autoShow : true,
    layout : 'border',
    border : false,

    initComponent : function(){
        this.items = [{
                /*
                 * Some other Ext Elements
                 */
            }, {
                region : 'east',
                xtype : 'extensible.calendarpanel',
                name : 'zeus-calendar',
                width : 500,
                eventStore: Ext.create('Extensible.calendar.data.EventStore', {
                    data: Ext.create('Extensible.calendar.data.EventModel',{
                        StartDate: '2101-01-12 12:00:00',
                        EndDate: '2101-01-12 13:30:00',
                        Title: 'My cool event',
                        Notes: 'Some notes'
                    })
                })
            }
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

Now it loads all classes correctly when the Extensible singleton is included, but nothing works. I just have a white screen and no functions in the controller or anywhere else are called. When I remove it from the requires list it comes up with this error: `Extensible.log is not a function`

Do I use the plugin at all right?

Any advice?

Comment: In the commented out 'other Ext Elements' you do have something with  region: 'center', right?

Comment: Yes I have. It is a completely working border layout. These parts were just picking up space in the question.

Comment: So, where exactly an error is coming from?

Comment: It is definitively coming from the calendarpanel call. I made a simplistic test app with this only call in my view class and it throws the same error.

Comment: Try to break it down. May be create a store beforehand, make sure store exists and then create calendar?

Comment: Hm... I put the store declaration and its content in a variable. I also registered `Extensible.calendar.CalendarPanel` in the view-list of my controller. Now it loads a huge bunch of classes, but still doesn't display anything...

Comment: I just noticed - it should be require_s_ not require.

Comment: I found the mistake. The xtype was misspelled and caused the error. But now it throws another error from the `AbstractCalendar.js`: `Extensible.log is not a function`... I will google that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensible.log is defined on the Extensible singleton, so it should always be available if your dependencies and includes are set up correctly. You really should post in the Extensible forums with additonal details (Ext version, Extensible version, script include markup) as this is basically a product support question.

EDIT: By the way, there is no such thing as Extensible.Extensible, which might be part of your problem. Also you cannot use wildcard requires statements for non-Sencha classes.  You might try getting a basic example working first before trying to create a complex layout with it.

Comment: Ok, I will explain my problem in your forum in a more detailed way. Thanks for the reply. Only as a stimulus, but could you add another example application to your examples, which shows how to implement the calendar in the ExtJS MVC pattern? I think this would prevent similar issues in the future.

Comment: Yes, I will do that when I get a chance. Should be easy enough.

Comment: Cool, thanks! By the way: I've posted the quesion at the extensible forums now.